# Differential equation $y'+10t=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation:
$$y'+10t=0$$

Then I write it to the form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$
$$y'=-10t$$

Then I find the integrating factor $I(x)=e^{\int a(x)dx}$
$$I(t)=e^{\int dt}=e^t$$

Now I multiply $I(t)$ on both sides
$$e^ty'=-10te^t$$

and the left hand side can be written as

$$y'\left( ye^t \right)=-10te^t$$

hereafter I integrate both sides
$$\int y' \left(ye^t \right)dt=\int -10te^t$$
$$ye^t=?$$

then I got stuck, can someone help?

Comment: You don't even need an integrating factor in this problem. You can just separate the variables and integrate

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dt}=-10 \cdot t \implies dy=-10 \cdot t ~ dt \implies y(t)=-5t^2 + C  $$

You don't need to use an integrating factor to solve this ODE, it is a separable one so you can integrate each variable separately.

Answer (score 2):

general form of first order linear D.E
$$y'+P(t)y=Q(t)$$
so here
$$P(t)=0$$
$$Q(t)=-10t$$

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly determined the integrating factor. Your equation is equivalent to $$y'+0y=-10t,$$ and so your integrating factor should be $$I(t)=e^{\int 0\,dt}=e^C$$ for some constant $C$. We can just take $C=0,$ which gives us an integrating factor of $1.$ Hence, there was *no need for an integrating factor*!

Instead, $$y=\int(-10t)\,dt,$$ which is straightforward.